# How to make the script dynamic for number of blocks

Tags: jquery, for-loop, while-loop

I have written a script for one block where in it add and removes active class. I want to make this script work for 20 more blocks without repeating the script.

```
    $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
          var targetTop = $("#block3").offset().top-80;
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= targetTop) {
            $('ul.bxslider li a').removeClass('active');
            $('ul.bxslider li a[href="#block3"]').addClass('active');
          }
          else{
            $('ul.bxslider li a[href="#block3"]').removeClass('active');
          }

          var targetTop = $("#block4").offset().top-80;
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= targetTop) {
            $('ul.bxslider li a').removeClass('active');
            $('ul.bxslider li a[href="#block4"]').addClass('active');
          }
          else{
            $('ul.bxslider li a[href="#block4"]').removeClass('active');
          }
       }
```

The above script works for block3 and block4. Please can anyone help me work this script for 20 more blocks having IDs block1,block2,block3, ..... ,block20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try revising your approach. Instead of using id for your blocks, use classes and then just iterate through them using $.each(). For each instance you can check if the block has reached the top of the window then use the id to manipulate the correct anchor tag. Like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
    $('.blockClass').each(function(index, element){
        var targetTop = $(element).offset().top-80;
        var id = $(element).attr('id');
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= targetTop) {
             $('ul.bxslider li a').removeClass('active');
             $('ul.bxslider li a[href="#' + id + '"]').addClass('active');
        }
        else {
             $('ul.bxslider li a[href="#' + id + '"]').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It is throwing error in console **key_milestones.html:733 Uncaught TypeError: element.offset is not a function(…)** @Peter

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typos. Try enclosing it in $(element)

Comment: You're welcome @monisha , don't forget to mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**make a function of that script and pass id into it like**

```
function blockCode(ID){
var targetTop = $("#"+ID).offset().top-80;
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= targetTop) {
            $('ul.bxslider li a').removeClass('active');
            $('ul.bxslider li a[href="#'+ID+'"]').addClass('active');
          }
          else{
            $('ul.bxslider li a[href="#'+ID+'"]').removeClass('active');
          }
}


blockCode('block4')
```

Comment: jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul.bxslider li a[href="#"+ID](…)  Where should I call the function blockCode('block4')

Comment: Yes its working now. But only for block4. Peters answer below is dynamic and solves my issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: the function works for the id you pass so it will work for all the ids but you must call that function by passing any id name

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the block into this function:

```
    process("#block3");


    function process(block){
      block = $(block);
      var targetTop = block.offset().top-80;
      $('ul.bxslider li a').removeClass('active');
      if ($(window).scrollTop() < targetTop) block.addClass('active');
    }
```

Comment: This script runs inside window.scroll(function()) . So every time any of the block reaches the top of window. This script should run for that particular block. For example if block3 reaches top of window then this should work for block3. Here each time the block should be passed in the function. How is it possible on scroll? Thanks in advance!